# How do I access a asp.net session variable from APP_CODE?

Tags: session, asp.net-session

I have seen lots of posts here and elsewhere stating that one can access session variables from app_code. I want to access an already created session.

this code errors out because of a null exception. 
string myFile = HttpContext.Current.Session["UploadedFile"];

this creates a null session variable. 
System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState Session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

It looks like I can create a new session variable but not access an already created one. Anyone have any idea what might be giving me problems?

Comment: Where is your code being run?

Comment: It is in the app_code directory in a web service. Both the following statements return null. The badly named session variable 'file' is set by this point in the code. 

string myfile = HttpContext.Current.Session["file"].ToString();
string FileName = Session["file"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

I was having ths same problem, but I was able to fix it because I controlled where in the event lifecycle I was attempting to leverage HttpContect.Current.Session... it makes a difference because Session isn't available, for example, on construction.

Maybe that will help you.